# expected 'const csim_stats_t * {aka const struct <anonymous> *}' but argument is of type 'csim_stats_t * {aka struct <anonymous> *}'

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors

As said in the title, I am trying to initialize my variable result but I get the following error

```
expected 'const csim_stats_t * {aka const struct <anonymous> *}' but argument is of type 'csim_stats_t * {aka struct <anonymous> *}'
```

Because of this, I'm unable to set any of the values inside the `struct csim_stats_t`. Can somebody help?

My struct has been defined as :

```
typedef struct {
    long hits;
    long misses;
    long evictions;
    long dirty_bytes;
    long dirty_evictions;
} csim_stats_t;
```

Comment: please give more detailed source code example. what you have tried to fix this issue?

Comment: So I was given the struct above and I tried to initialize a variable "result" by doing const csim_stats_t *result = malloc(sizeof(csim_stats_t)). Then I got that error. I haven't done anything except that because I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to write to a `const` variable, but you posted no code to show that part.

Comment: So it got solved when I removed the const in front of my variable result. Much thanks!!!